# apache redirect http to https and www to non www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

basically what i want is redirect al request to use HTTPS instead of http

I have this in my htaccess so far and it worked great: 
Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
</ifModule>
```

today someone noticed that when going to: 
http://www.example.com it redirects to  and shows an unsecure connection thingie.

My ssl is setup for non www domain: mydomain.com

So i need to make sure all site requests are sent to non www and https: 
It works fine if i put example.com it redirects to https://example.com

but with www.example.com it goes to htts://www.example.com and shows the error

what do i need to add to my code to redirect www to non www and then to ssl 
?

Comment: What common names are in your certificate ? Most CAs put www and non-www in the common name when they issue a certificate for avoiding this kind of issue.

Comment: certificat is made for domain.com (non www)
basically i want all trafic to go to NON www and https

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get what you need from the HTTP_HOST

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This way it will get the host always without the subdomain.

Comment: +1 but you should really change RewriteRule line to: `RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: I don't think this answer will solve OP's issue concerning visitors receiving a warning, though.

Comment: @baynezy code will only redirect non-ssl connections. This does not solve your issue about redirecting `https://www.mysite.com` to `https://mysite.com` or visitors receiving a warning when visiting `https://www.mysite.com`

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois truee but no one will type https:// www.
most will put just www.domain.com and that now redirects to https://

Comment: does not solve the  `https://www.mysite.com` redirection to `https://mysite.com` issue

Comment: I've searched for hours and this is the only answer that has worked. Keep in mind that the above comments are right though. This will work for almost every instance except if they start with `https://www.` and not `http://www`

Answer (score 25):

You will have to re-issue your certificate for both www and without www.

If someone connects to your site via a domain name that is not included in your common name, they will receive a warning.

The ssl negociation process happens **before** any response from the server (in your case, a redirection), so in all cases, your visitors will receive a warning when using a domain that is not in your common name.

Comment: Your answer should be marked as the correct one, but I also must note that currently, Chrome does handle 301 redirects before the certificate is validated with no warning to the user, while Safari does not.  The universal way is to do it as you explain.

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CloudFlare's free account then that's the problem.  CloudFlare's free account does NOT support SSL Certificates.  To continue using CloudFlare's free account with an SSL Certificate just go to the DNS settings in CloudFlare and take the orange cloud off of your domain and off of the cname WWW.  That will fix your problem and cause both www and non-www to be redirected to https.

Also be sure to add this code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then, everything should work!

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect all of your www websites to non-www and secure them if you have completed the CERTBOT for each domain conf file. Put this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf inside the Directory /www section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

There is no need to CERTBOT a www domain after this code is inserted. Just do the domain.com choice. You do not need htaccess files. They can be restricted by the AllowOverride None selection.

Remember to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```