# htaccess to redirect whole website to https doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using the below script to redirect traffic to https.  It work fine if I just type domain.com in the address bar but if I type www.domain.com it doesn't get redirected.  How do I make it redirect both with and without www?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: The issue you get is exactly what the second line does

Comment: I tried to get rid of the second line liek above.  It works in safari but in firefox it gets The page isn't redirecting properly message

Comment: Maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**RewriteEngine On**

**RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80**

**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]**

- In case you wish to force HTTPS for a particular folder you can use:

**RewriteEngine On**

**RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80**

**RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} somefolder**

**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/somefolder/$1 [R,L]**

Thanks