# Redirect non-www and non-http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Yesterday I Installed SSL on the server. Since than I can't reach some pages.

> www.example.com/amsterdam/shoes
>
> example.com/amsterdam/

^ both do not redirect to https://, not even http://

> www.example.com/amsterdam

^ does redirect to https://

How do I redirect all pages to `HTTPS`  with `www` via .htaccess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache redirect http to https and www to non www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

This will redirect both `http` or `non-www` to `https://www`

Comment: thanks, this works for me. do you have a reason for not using R=301 or NE ? (I've seen this a lot with other redirects)

Comment: @Bombelman Sorry, that was a typo. I have updated my answer with `R=301,NE` flags. Thanks for your comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

OR you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```