# Redirect www. to non-www and redirect all http to https with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Million times asked question, but after reading many of the answers here on SO I still can't figure this out. I need to redirect all requests like below:

1. http://domain.tld > https://domain.tld
2. http://www.domain.tld > https://domain.tld
3. https://www.domain.tld > https://domain.tld
4. http://sub.domain.tld > https://sub.domain.tld (when .htaccess placed in subdomain folder)

Until now, I was using the code from html5boilerplate, that solved www to non-www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

they also have a code for http to https redirect, but after adding this piece of code (above the www redirect), page is loading and after a timeout it shows error/too many redirects

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried examples like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www) but still the website doesn't work. Only solution for now is to use the first piece of code and replace `http` with `https` but that doesn't solve most important redirect (1)

current full `.htaccess` content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] #by uncommenting this, site stops working
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, depending on some server configuration, it appears that `HTTPS` variable is always set to `off`. That would explain the loop, and i've already seen a similar case here on SO.

A simple workaround would be to test `SERVER_PORT` (if you use default 80 and 443) or you could also test `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Example (1) to test if it is **not** `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

Example (2) to test if it is **not** `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !403
```

Comment: Thank you Justin, example 1 works perfectly on all hostings, example 2 behaves the same as others, too many redirects

Comment: so, on one hosting, example 2 works and example 1 doesn't. good to have all possible solutions to it!

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to https and non-www in a single http request, you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this rule.

Comment: Tried it, but still I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in Chrome, after Clean Cache and Hard Reload. I get https://domain.tld correctly, but after that, it's loading and throws error

Comment: Are you using cloud flare?

Comment: No, I'm not using CF or any other CDN. I just installed Let's Encrypt certificate and wanted to use it (it works fine if I go directly to https: page or use www.domain)