# Redirect https://www to https://non-www

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like that all these addresses:

1. `http://www.example.com` *(currently correctly redirecting with my .htaccess file)*
2. `http://example.com` *(currently correctly redirecting with my .htaccess file)*
3. `https://www.example.com` **(this address does not redirect)**

redirect to `https://example.com`.

With the following `.htaccess` file, I can only get the 1. and 2. addresses redirect to `https://example.com`.

Only `https://www.example.com` is still not redirecting to `https://example.com`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# URL with www rewrite to https without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# URL without www rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945803/5019802) it might be helpful.

Comment: #3 Should be redirected by the first rule (in the same way it redirects #1). If it's not then _something else_ would seem to be at play here. However, you should avoid adding custom directives between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers since WordPress itself maintains this section and will try to overwrite these directives in future updates.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is surely a duplicate but I can't find a decent one to point to.

```
# URL with wrong domain to right one + https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/$0 [L,R=301]

# URL with no https fix (domain already correct otherwise first rule would have matched)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [L,R=301]
```