# how do i redirect a domain name to an alternate on the same site? i.e example1.com to example2.com; both the same site via htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

All the examples I've found have something along the lines of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to catch in my `.htaccess` despite online syntax checkers telling me everything is fine and it'll fire.

I have a bunch of non conflicting individual page RewriteRules that don't conflict with this and fire off fine so I know mod rewrite is working and i'm stumped.

olddomain is a domain that used to reside on a different server but its dns is being pointed at newdomain so all these rules are firing off on the same site if that matters

Comment: The rule you posted should work unless you have conflicting rules (which you say there are none). Please include your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place. So, what is currently happening when requesting `olddomain.com`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect https://www to https://non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868410/redirect-https-www-to-https-non-www) It applies to making any domain the canonical one, not just changing the `www.` prefix.