# htaccess redirect for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently, I have a website (example.com). http to https redirect is working via my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This website also runs on subdomains.

If someone goes to www.subdomain.example.com of the website, I want them to be redirected to https://subdomain.example.com.

Is it possible to achieve this with the htaccess file without impacting the http to https redirect that I have working for example.com?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache redirect http to https and www to non www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add multiple conditions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

1: If the  HOST is `www.subdomain.example.com`, redirect to `https://subdomain.example.com/`

2: If its not `https`, redirect to `https`.

Comment: how can I prevent the subdomain and domain from being hard coded? My site will run multiple domains and multiple subdomains for each site.